# Ubuntu 18.04 driver for dell uz2315h integrated webcam

Tags: drivers, dell, monitor, webcam

My Integrated webcam in the Dell video monitor UZ2315H is not found by all video applications such as 'cheese' and 'skype'.
Running the command `lsusb -t` produces:

```
/:  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/6p, 5000M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/14p, 480M
    |__ Port 3: Dev 114, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 115, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 115, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 91, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 91, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=, 480M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 116, If 2, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 116, If 0, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 116, If 3, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 116, If 1, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
    |__ Port 5: Dev 8, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
    |__ Port 6: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
    |__ Port 6: Dev 5, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/8p, 480M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/6p, 480M
```

Clearly, one video class port is missing a driver (Bus 03::Port 3::Port 4)

The accompanying CD-ROM that came with the monitor doesn't include a Linux driver. (In fact the CD browser is not Linux compatible.) Also, the Dell site doesn't have a Linux driver of any Linux distribution. Finally, searching the web didn't yield a solution either.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while, I tried again the `lsusb -t` and its relevant lines were:

```
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/14p, 480M
|__ Port 3: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 58, If 1, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 58, If 0, Class=Video, Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
```

namely the driver that was missing suddenly appears and by no action on my part. Strange...!

And `cheese` and `skype` both find the integrated webcam and display video!

Regards

Meir